# iOS 9 Master/Detail Template Hiding Toolbar on Push

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

I am using the Master/Detail template for my app and set the navigation controller to display the bottom bar (toolbar) for the Master controller and Detail controller. My issue is that when I select an item from the list and the Detail controller is pushed the toolbar on the Master controller hides itself. When I press back and it returns to the Master controller the toolbar stays hidden until the animation is complete. I have done some search and can't figure out why this is happening. I added:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

to

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated;
```

which seems to get it displaying correctly when I go back from the Detail controller but you can still see it disappearing from the Master controller when you select an item and it begins the animations to push the Detail controller into view. I tried adding the same line to

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

but it is not helping.
I have looking through the storyboard files but couldn't seem to find any settings that would cause this.

If anyone has any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it that would be wonderful. Thanks.